# Break image out of parent <div> with css only

Tags: html, css

I'd like to break an image out of the parent div. The main problem I have is that I don't know the original image width or height. I'm also not able to use any javascript to fix it.

Using `position:absolute;` has the right effect on the image, but the `<p></p>` content below then rides up underneath the image.

[image: Image breaking out of parent div]

HTML:

```
    <div>
        <h1>Some Title</h1>
        <figure>
            <img src="someimage.jpg" />
        </figure>
        <p>Some description</p>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    width:700px;
    }

img{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0px 0 0 -40%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    }
```

Edit: the image should never be wider than the browser window (and hence trigger scrolling)

Answer (score 3):

I guess, what you want is, your `paragraph` to be always just below the image.

and since you have made your img `position:absolute`, it will behave independent of it's parent div. that's why the paragraph gets rendered just after the h1 tag.

also, fixations through setting `margin` values of a `position:absolute` element, or padding, won't help you much, as you can never tell what width and size your image can be, combined with range of resolutions(including IE). so i'am not gonna suggest you those temporary workouts:

What best you should do in my views is, changing your layout structure: see, anyway, content-area behind your img is not going to be visible, so why not keep three separate containers?
and position them relatively?

see this markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
            <div class='header'>
                <h1>Some Title</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <figure>
                    <img src="someimage.jpg" />
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="para">
                <p id="paragraph">Some description</p>
            </div>
</div>
```

and see this css:

```
 .header
    {
        position: relative;
        left:10%;
        width:80%;
        height: 20%;
        background-color: #CCCCCC;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .wrapper
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .image
    {
        position: relative;
        top:20%;
        width: auto;
        background-color: #EEEEEE;
        height: auto; 
        text-align: center;
    }
    .image > figure >img
    {
        width: 1800px;
        height: 800px;
        border:1px Solid #CCCCCC;
    }
    .para
    {
        position: relative;
        left:10%;
        width:80%;
        height: 20%;
        background-color: #555555;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra256/FkyF9/1/)

benefits:

1. this will work in all resolutions.
2. your paragraph container will position itself according to the img height;
3. right now, i've given a very high value for the img, all you have to do is to set height and width of the img to 100%, so that it remains original.

it should work. tell me if it doesn't

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not able to use javascript to solve this issue. Should be css only :)

Comment: please see my answer, i tried to give you a css only, and without position:absolute way to handle this

Comment: thanks, but I'm not sure that works. Check out the jsfiddle to see if I implemented it right: http://jsfiddle.net/edlea/Ds9Kr/

Comment: it will scale according to your image size, as the middle container has auto width and height: and also lower para container has auto top.as for the space b/w the individual containers, you can control that by removing padding and margin for 'figure' element and 'p' element. I've updated your fiddle..see if that is what you want

Comment: Thanks Manish. I'm not sure you can update my fiddle. I tweaked it a little to show you that I'm not sure your solution is working. http://jsfiddle.net/edlea/Ds9Kr/2/ You can see that the 900px image is not breaking out of the 700px wrapper. But don't worry about spending anymore time, just FYI.

Comment: god. that's the whole point of separating your 3 elements, wrapper is for controlling all three together. you can never break out of the parent div unless your div is absolute. that's why we made three separate containers and placed them one beneath other.that way your middle element i.e. the image will be independent and can be of any width

Comment: so how exactly is it "breaking out" if "you can never break out" of ```<div class="wrapper">```? Stacking 3 different widths of element on top of each other is not really tackling the problem.

Comment: @ed209 ,a child container cannot breakout of the parent, if it has extra width or height, scrollbars will appear. That's the rule! nothing can be done about it.(and its better this way). but still you want a layout as in your question image.than stacking different divs one over another, playing with absolute divs. giving non-practical margins, thats what you do. besides, stacking different divs is most elegant way. I intended to show you the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess you can have a static width on the `div`? And you can have the maximum size of the image? If so, try [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/VrrBY/).

Basically, I set the div to `width:500px` and figure to be `700px`. Now, the figure is `200px` bigger than its container (`100px` each side) so I move the figure to the left by the `100px` (it's not elegant solution as you should avoid negative margins but I had to use it for demonstration purpose) and I put center align on the figure. This will always put the image in the middle of the figure. I hope it makes sense!

Comment: This solution is not applicable since op doesn't know the exact dimensions of the image.

Comment: My solution does not require size of an image, however, it does assume that the width of the wrapper is provided.

Comment: but you're specifying the width of ```<figure>``` but I don't know what that is. It can't be a fixed value.

Comment: What about the div? Can you put static width there?

Answer (score 0):

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vNKYL/)**

```
div{
    width:700px;
    background:#000;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
}

img{
    width: 120%;
    margin: 0px 0 0 -10%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

The HTML remains unchanged. Some of the CSS is for the example (like the background-color).

Anyways, setting the `img` to `position:relative` will make it so the text will remain under the image. Instead of `margin: 0 0 0 -10%`, `left: -10%` would also work.

Comment: This scales the picture to a fix value of 120% of the patent container, which is not what OP wants.

Comment: thanks! I tried this route also, but there are problems when it comes to varying browser window sizes.